# NameError: name is not defined in python init function

Tags: python, init, nameerror

```
class HumidityServer(CoAP):
    def __init__(self, host, port, noOfSensors=10, multicast=False):
        CoAP.__init__(self, (host, port), multicast)

        for num in range(noOfSensors):
            self.add_resource('humidity'+num+'/', HumidityResource(num))
```

This excerpt is part of a program that generates:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "humidityserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    class HumidityServer(CoAP):
  File "humidityserver.py", line 14, in HumidityServer
    for num in range(noOfSensors):
NameError: name 'noOfSensors' is not defined
```

Why does this happen even though I've defined a default value for the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in your code; this is your original code as pasted into the question:

[image]

The solid grey lines are tabs, the dots are spaces.

Note how the `for` loop is indented to 8 spaces, buth `def __init__` is indented by one tab? Python expands tabs to **eight** spaces, not four, so to Python your code looks like this instead:

[image: source code at 8 spaces per tab]

Now you can see that the `for` loop is **outside** the `__init__` method, and the `noOfSensors` variable from the `__init__` function signature is not defined there.

Don't mix tabs and spaces in indentation, stick to *just* tabs or *just* spaces. The PEP 8 Python style guide [strongly advises you to use only spaces for indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). Your editor can easily be configured to insert spaces whenever you use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, for example.

Comment: @Sandi: Sublime Text 3, using the Monokay colour scheme.

Answer (score -1):

I copied and run the code, it was not because of the mixing tabs and spaces issues answered by @Martijn. I have just ran into a similar issue while creating a small game based on classes.

Even though I have assigned a default value into the variable but it stuck and gave me error:

```
NameError: name 'mental' is not defined #where mental is the variable
```

I research a bit and saw somebody talking about instances. Then I tried to create an instance and make the instance execute the function, meanwhile I define a function to what I intended to execute. And it works out. Below is my example on the fix:

```
class People(object):
    def __init__(self, vital, mental):
    self.vital = vital
    self.mental = mental

class Andy(People):
        print "My name is Andy... I am not the killer! Trust me..."
        chat1 = raw_input(">")
        if chat1 == ('i believe you' or 'yes i believe' or 'believe' or 'i trust you' or 'yes i trust you'):
            self.mental += -1
            print "(checking) option 1"
        elif chat1 == ('you are killer' or 'you are the one' or 'really?' or 'i doubt' or 'i don\'t believe' or 'i don\'t trust you'):
            self.mental += 1
            print "(checking) option 2"
        else:
            print "Pass to else"
            print self.mental
            print self.vital

andy = Andy(1, 5)
```

The solution I found was:

```
class People(object):
    def __init__(self, vital, mental):
    self.vital = vital
    self.mental = mental

class Andy(People):
    def play(self):
        print "My name is Andy... I am not the killer! Trust me..."
        chat1 = raw_input(">")
        if chat1 == ('i believe you' or 'yes i believe' or 'believe' or 'i trust you' or 'yes i trust you'):
            self.mental += -1
            print "(checking) option 1"
        elif chat1 == ('you are killer' or 'you are the one' or 'really?' or 'i doubt' or 'i don\'t believe' or 'i don\'t trust you'):
            self.mental += 1
            print "(checking) option 2"
        else:
            print "Pass to else"
            print self.mental
            print self.vital

andy = Andy(1, 5)
andy.play()
```

Maybe there are other solutions to your question, but I am quite new in programming, there are stuff in your code I don't understand. But regarding to the error you get I think its because of the 'self' has to be an instance you set for it to run through the class. Please correct me if I got the concept wrong.

Answer (score -4):

it's not instanced Yet so the defalut value executed when class is Created man